# php DateTime object with unix timestamp wrong - bug?

Tags: php, datetime, unix-timestamp

Just stumbled upon this weird bug with php's DateTime object...
Check this out:

```
<?php
$date = 1335823200;
echo date('d',$date);
echo '<br />';
$date = new DateTime("@$date");
echo $date->format('d');
?>
```

Returns:

```
06
05
```

It doesn't happen with any timestamp. I suspect that it has something to do with different timezones, but playing around with setlocale() didn't help anything. By the way, the '@' in the DateTime is needed to be able to use unix timestamps (see bug report [here](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=40171)). Here a few more timestamps to test:

```
1333663200
1338588000
1338847200
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you did not specify timezone for `DateTime` it is supposed that it is `UTC`, while `date` respects current timezone (specified by `date_default_timezone_set` or taken from `php.ini`). Just execute this and see:

```
$date = 1335823200;
echo date('d-m-Y  H:i:s',$date);
echo '<br />';
$date = new DateTime("@$date");
echo $date->format('d-m-Y H:i:s');
```

Comment: Damn, I thought it would both just use the settings from the same source. Do you know if I can globally define a default for DateTime (before instanciating)?

Comment: @danontheline: manual says that php *should* use default timezone, but actually on my php 5.2 it is not correct. Probably it has been fixed in 5.3